# Flutter - Circular menu from bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have created a bottom navigation menu in my app and i would like to create an animated circular menu when i click on the transact button.

[image]

When i click on transact i want it to pull up like this

[image]

This is my current bottomNav code

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        label: 'Home',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.swap_horiz),
        label: 'Transact',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
        label: 'Settings',
      ),
    ],
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
    selectedItemColor: MyColors.greenSuccess,
    onTap: _onItemTapped,
  ),

//function when item is tapped
void _onItemTapped(int index) {
setState(() {
  _selectedIndex = index;
});

//check which item is selected
if(index == 0){
  //go home
}
else if(index == 1){
  //open trans menu here

}
else{
  // go to settings

}
}
```

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/expandable-fab

Comment: @ManishDayma i saw the FAB solution but this is not a FAB

Comment: can you try with create a dialogue and place at bottom with proper design

Comment: https://fluttergems.dev/floating-action-button/#:~:text=A%20floating%20action%20button%20(FAB,right%20corner%20of%20the%20screen.

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot of bottom nav variation package you can check at this [website](https://fluttergems.dev/bottom-navigation-bar/)

or you can try to use bottom nav with this [FAB](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_menu) put in in the center of the nav